# Color of the circle is not changing like I want it to

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a code where you are presented with a 800x800 screen with 4 circles at the bottom. Whenever you press a button (like d), those buttons should hypothetically turn white for maybe a few seconds, and then turn back into their original color (blue).

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=800, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                   bg="black")
canvas.grid()




def press_d(event = ' '):
    global color
    x = 0
    print('d is pressed', color)
    color = 'white'
    print(color, 'is the color')
    time.sleep(0.2)
    while color != 'blue':
        for i in range(3):
            x += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(x)
        if x >= 3:
            color = 'blue'
            print(color, 'new color')
        
    


    return color

def press_f(event = ' '):
    global color
    print('f is pressed')
    color = 'blue'


    return color

root.bind('d', press_d)
root.bind('f', press_f)

def game():
    global color
    color = 'blue'
    root.title("Circles and Arcs")

    x = 1
    while x != 12:
        #print('x ')
        num = 0
        canvas.create_oval(50,770,160,660, fill = color, outline = '#DDD', width = 4)
        canvas.create_oval(250,770,355 ,660, fill = color, outline = '#DDD', width = 4)
        canvas.create_oval(450,770,555 ,660, fill = color, outline = '#DDD', width = 4)
        canvas.create_oval(650,770,755 ,660, fill = color, outline = '#DDD', width = 4)
        
        canvas.create_oval(650,770,755 ,660, fill = color, outline = '#DDD', width = 4)
        canvas.pack()
        
        canvas.update()
    #Show picture to user

    root.mainloop()



game()
```

if you look at `def press_d(event = ' '):`, that is the function that controls the whole turning circles white for a second and then blue again.

```
def press_d(event = ' '):
global color
x = 0
print('d is pressed', color)
color = 'white'
print(color, 'is the color')
time.sleep(0.2)
while color != 'blue':
    for i in range(3):
        x += 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(x)
    if x >= 3:
        color = 'blue'
        print(color, 'new color')




return color
```

my logic is this. when 'd' is pressed, the color is initially set to white. That means the circles will turn white. Then, in a while loop, about 3 ish seconds pass and the color turns blue. Then the color is returned and set into the circle in the game() function.

HOWEVER, whenever I press d, the circle doesn't change color. However, the var color does infact go through the process of changing to white when d is pressed, then waiting 3 increments and changing to blue.

I understand the issue is the `return color` statement. the var color does go through the changes, but the end result of color is always blue. And blue is what's send to the circle color.

I need help trying to make it so that the color function's changes go through to the circle fill.
If possible, please make the code intermediate style and not complicated. I want to be able to atleast understand the solution.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You can't use `time.sleep()` here - all that does is lock up the GUI, no display updates will occur until you return to the mainloop.  You want to use `.after()` instead, to schedule the next step of the color change at a time in the future.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks for the suggestion. could u give me an example about using .after() in my code to make it wait and change color?
What variable would i need to add .after() with?